# Why is the word 'number' abbreviated to 'No.' in UK English and '#' in American English?

Tags: etymology, abbreviations, symbols

Why the disparity? And why use 'No.'? Is it from the French?

And the *hash* or *pound sign* seems a weird choice too, is there a history or any reason involved?

Comment: *No.* is also used in the US.

Comment: It seems to be something of an old-fashioned usage in the states though? More something you'd seen on a 'vintage' styled product.

I'm think of such things as Amazon order numbers which are always prefixed by the `pound` sign ('#').

While we're on the topic, I'd just like to remind American users of this site that '£' is the pound sign ;-)

Comment: "Old fashioned" is a bit strong, but I would agree that its use is waning. Addresses tend to use # for an apartment number, for example, but it's not uncommon to see "take the No. 9 train" or "look at paragraph No. 7".

Comment: So, in the UK, when they (used to) give weights in the pounds, they used £ ??  Learned something new today, I thought that was only for money.

Comment: @GEdgar - not exactly. The pound sign evolved from the usage of the upper-case 'L' which was used to abbreviate the Latin word 'libra' (literal meaning 'scales') which was what mass was expressed in in Roman times. 1 libra approx. = 12oz.

Comment: Note that the abbreviation in French has the “o” superscripted and no dot.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**No.** comes from the abbreviation of ["numero",](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Number.html) ablative case of the Latin "numerus"

Also, `#` was used in America for an interesting reason:

> In the United States, the symbol is traditionally called the pound sign or the number sign. The pound name derives from a series of abbreviations for pound, the unit of weight. At first "lb." was used; however, printers later designed a font containing a special symbol of an "lb" with a line through the verticals so that the lowercase letter "l" would not be mistaken for the numeral/digit "1". Unicode character U+2114 (℔) is called the "L B bar symbol", and it is a cursive development of this symbol. Ultimately, the symbol was reduced for clarity as an overlay of two horizontal strokes "=" across two forward-slash-like strokes "//"<sup>1</sup>

The `#` in America ultimately became used for numbering everything, not just in weight, but in any quantity.

The reason the # wasn't used as a numbering sign in England was because the pound in England was denoted by the (£) sign, so `#` wasn't used to avoid confusion.

<sup>1</sup> The above was taken from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign#cite_note-nyt-0)

Comment: The # symbol is still used for "pound" in specialized applications, such as "24# bond paper."

Answer (score 7):

I consider this etymology to be more correct for `No.`, since [No.](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/no_1) is not an acronym but an abbreviation:

> **No.**
>   ORIGIN: from Latin **numero**, ablative of **numerus** ‘*number*.’ ]

I couldn't find anything on the # symbol yet, I guess that wikipedia article is the only source. I'll make sure to edit in case I find something else.