# What is a thorpe?

Tags: etymology, punctuation, semantics

`#` is an octothorpe

`*` is a hexathorpe

`+` a quadrathorpe

`-` a duothorpe

but What is a thorpe???

This question came from an [argument in comments on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/675448/2043621) that started over an American calling a `#` a pound sign.

Comment: I guess the question here is one of etymology. Who decided points on random scribblings were "thorps?"

Comment: From your other definitions, I guess it would be a line with one end missing.

Comment: From [OxfordDictionariesOnline:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/octothorp) ***octothorpe** 1970s: of uncertain origin; probably from octo- (referring to the eight points on the symbol) + **the surname Thorpe.*** You can also look up ***thorpe** = village or hamlet* in that same dictionary, but that obsolete word probably has no relevance to your question.

Comment: Maybe it's just a dot. "."

Comment: The # originally ***was*** the pound sign. It seems to have started out in the U.S. as a handwritten (never printed) variant of ℔ (lb with a slash through it), somehow been incorporated into American typewriters, and then also used as an abbreviation for number. It was then put on the telephone keypads, then computer keyboards, and from these it spread internationally. I believe only Americans ever used it to stand  for pounds (weight, not currency). Somebody at AT&T (remember telephone keypads above) coined the name *"octothorp"*. Nobody now remembers why.

Comment: A Thorpe is a gold-medalist swimmer.  So it follows that '-' means two gold medalist swimmers, and so on.  (Sorry, I couldn't resist)

Comment: @PeterShor; With some references and a distinction between '*a* pound sign' and '*the* pound sign'(which was £ long before the U.S. existed,) that would be a useful answer.

Comment: Related ["What is the real name of the #?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161720/what-is-the-real-name-of-the/163328#163328)

Comment: @Mari-LouA If you read the full text of the Bell Labs article linked a few places in answers/comments, it seems its official name is "Number Sign."

Comment: @BrianHooper Could you post a picture of your proposed "line with one end missing?" (And no, I won't accept a circle as that would equate to a Null-thorpe.)

Comment: @Okuma.Tony, I'm sorry to say I cannot. But you can avoid terminological difficulties of this sort by using an [older programming language](http://3e8.org/pub/intercal.pdf), in which these characters are called _mesh_, _splat_, _intersection_ and _worm_.

Comment: @BrianHooper Priceless. I just skimmed the whole manual. I'm printing that and posting it at work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### *Thorpe*

The *-thorpe* comes from *octothorpe.* Its origins are unknown. The other words are rare and likely variations after *octothorpe*.

### *Octothorpe*

The OED says of *octothorpe*:

> The term was reportedly coined in the early 1960s by Don Macpherson, an employee of Bell Laboratories:
>
> > 1996   *Telecom Heritage* No. 28. 53   His thought process was as follows: There are eight points on the symbol so *octo* should be part of the name. We need a few more letters or another syllable to make a noun... (Don Macpherson..was active in a group that was trying to get Jim Thorpe's Olympic medals returned from Sweden). The phrase *thorpe* would be unique.
>
> For an alternative explanation see quot. 1996; in a variant of this explanation, the word is explained as arising from the use of the symbol in cartography to represent a village.
>
> For a different explanation from a former employee of Bell Laboratories, arguing that the word is a completely arbitrary formation (and that it originally had the form octatherp) see D. A. Kerr ‘The ASCII Character *Octatherp*’ in *http://doug.kerr.home.att.net* (2006).

Quot. 1996 is:

> 1996   *New Scientist* 30 Mar. 54/3   The term ‘octothorp(e)’ (which MWCD10 dates 1971) was invented for ‘#’, allegedly by Bell Labs engineers when touch-tone telephones were introduced in the mid-1960s. ‘Octo-’ means eight, and ‘thorp’ was an Old English word for village: apparently the sign was playfully construed as eight fields surrounding a village.

### *Hexathorpe, quadrathorpe* and *duothorpe*

*Hexathorpe, quadrathorpe* and *duothorpe* don't appear in the OED and I suspect they're variations after *octothorpe*. They also don't figure in this [Google Ngrams chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=octothorpe%2C%20hexathorpe%2C%20quadrathorpe%2C%20duothorpe&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coctothorpe%3B%2Cc0) and a quick search of Usenet shows they're usually mentioned in reference to the *octothorpe*.

Comment: The octothorpe (the character, not necessarily the name) certainly dates no later than 1963, as it was present in very early versions of the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) standard for character encoding.

Comment: @HotLicks... 1963?  Pfui! Remington typewriter, 1886.

Comment: AT&T's Kerr's document is archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20081221092652/http://doug.kerr.home.att.net/pumpkin/Octatherp.pdf . It explains that it was purely a practical joke, and laughs at the "thorp"/"therp" Old-English/Old-German theory that came afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Wikitionary specifically says *the etymology of [octothorpe](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/octothorpe) is **unclear and disputed***, but one contender is:

> In cartography, the octothorp (`#`) is a traditional symbol for village: eight fields around a central square.
>
> From *octo*- (“eight”) and *[thorpe](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thorpe#English) (“**field, hamlet or small village**”).*
>
> That is the source of its name. Octothorp means eight fields.

Which is as plausible as any of the other candidate etymologies, and more satisfying (the others being intentional, and uninteresting, jocular coinages).

Comment: I think that's a "folk etymology" - it's the sort of thing people would *like* to believe, so it'll appear in things like Wiktionary. But it's not even mentioned by OED (who also agree it's "etymology uncertain", but they suggest "the surname Thorpe"). I really can't see how such an obscure obsolete aspect of cartography could be relevant to a 1970s coinage which specifically arose in the context of hi-tech stuff like telephone keypads and computer programming symbol sets.

Comment: Yeah, who could imagine [nerds who are obsessed with computers][http://stackoverflow.com] also really being into [weird old words][http://english.stackexchange.com]? :)  Kidding aside, I think the **real answer here is "no one knows"**; I'm just rooting for the most interesting etymology.

Comment: Perhaps we have different ideas as to what *as plausible as any of the other candidate etymologies* means. To me, if OED say it's "uncertain", but only list *one* of the possibilities, my natural inclination is to assume the one they listed is the one they think is most likely to be true. And since they know more about such things than me, I'm happy to say their suggestion is *by definition* the "most plausible".

Comment: My answer was made in the context of the etymology given in the Wiktionary, as I do not have access to the OED.

Comment: [This](http://dougkerr.net/Pumpkin/articles/Octatherp.pdf) is the only plausible etymology I've ever seen. It was originally a practical joke. Why wasn't this known 40 years earlier? Consider: If you'd played a practical joke at work that got out of hand and resulted in a ridiculous-sounding word being added to the OED, would you tell your supervisors?

Comment: @peter: Yes, that was linked from the Wiktionary entry; I didn't choose it because it wasn't treated with any particular distinction in that source.  But since you went to the trouble of finding the memoirs themselves, if post it as an answer, I'll give you a +1.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The OED actually expands on the etymology in their full entry: "The term was reportedly coined in the early 1960s by Don Macpherson, an employee of Bell Laboratories ... / For a different explanation from a former employee of Bell Laboratories, arguing that the word is a completely arbitrary formation (and that it originally had the form octatherp) see ..." and then cites the explanation Peter Shor linked above.

It also mentions the variant explanation that the # was used in cartography as a symbol for a village.

Their earliest citation is 1973 in U.S. Patent 3,920,926.

Comment: @szarka: Ah, right: I never clicked on the "Show more" hotspot. I still don't buy the "hamlet" origin, and I still think whatever OED list *before* the "Show more" button is more likely to be what *they* believe, rather than anything buried in the murky details.