# How to pronounce %d in C programming language?

Tags: pronunciation, programming

How do we pronounce `%`, in something like `%d`? Is it pronounced as:

1. *per-cent d*
2. *mod d*

or, is there some other accepted/generalized way?

Comment: It is context-specific, even in C.

Comment: @Lawrence I am specifically referring to format specifiers, as in `printf("%d", ...)` and not in modulo operations.

Comment: May I suggest you ask here https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it relates to a specialist field and should be asked on our Computer Science stack exchange.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question by saying *I am specifically referring to format specifiers, as in printf("%d", ...) and **not in modulo operations.*** If the "mod" interpretation isn't relevant, ***don't use it***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers does that mean I pronounce it as **percent**?

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica the reason I asked here was that I saw a question of a similar type on this SE.

Comment: The vote to close isn't meant as a criticism. We get so many off-topic questions that sometimes the odd one slips through, so I understand that you may have seen this kind of question here. Nonetheless, your question is so profession-specific that it's unlikely to be useful to general users on EL&U, whereas it would be quite appropriate to ask on the CS site - see https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. :-)

Comment: Your question also needs more detail, no matter which site you ask it on. How you *pronounce* it must surely depend to some extent on which country or region you're in?

Comment: @ChappoHasn'tForgottenMonica Oh no, I didn't take it as criticism. This wasn't suitable for Stack Overflow so I asked here. Anyway, I'll ask it on CS SE, thanks for the suggestion. And the pronunciation is more of a religious thing than country-dependent ;)

Comment: Yes. The *default* name for the % symbol is "percent [sign]", so even though the usage in a printf() format string is nothing to do with either "modulo" OR "for each 100", you should use that default name.

Comment: (In retrospect, I now regret my closevote. You can't really look up a percent sign in many dictionaries, and if [What Is the Real Name of the #?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161720/what-is-the-real-name-of-the) was a valid ELU question, it's not obvious to me this one is so very different.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pronunciation depends on the context.

In most cases, you would say *percent*. A couple of examples:

- for a percentage (such as `printf("100%")`), you would say "100 percent"
- within a format string (such as `printf("%d", 2)`), you would say "printf of percent d"

As a modulo operator, you would say *mod*.

- `rem = a % 2` would be pronounced "a mod 2"

Comment: But it's ***not*** "for a **percentage**, in a format string". The use in format strings is purely a ***convention***, which no more relates to "percentage" than it does to "modulo".

Comment: Agreed, and I have reworded the examples to reflect the convention.